# ACS - bypassing user redirection to IdP?

Tags: acs

I have only recently been looking into ACS, AAL, WAAD and I would like to avoid redirecting users to the login page of their IDP. I want to keep my users within my site and present them with a dropdown to choose who they wish to authenticate with and an area to request a username and password, then acquire token via code. Is this possible?

I have been reviewing some sample applications and produce a quick mock-up, but cant seem to get things working e.g.

```
        _authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://littledeadbunny.accesscontrol.windows.net");

        string enteredEmailDomain = UserNameTextbox.Text.Substring(UserNameTextbox.Text.IndexOf('@') + 1);

        IList<IdentityProviderDescriptor> idpdList = _authContext.GetProviders("http://littledeadbunny.com/NonInteractive");
        foreach (IdentityProviderDescriptor idpd in idpdList)
        {
            if (String.Compare(ServiceRealmDropDownList.SelectedValue, idpd.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                Credential credential;
                credential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(enteredEmailDomain, UserNameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text);

                _assertionCredential = _authContext.AcquireToken("http://littledeadbunny.com/NonInteractive", idpd, credential);

                return;
            }
        }
```

Using the code above, when I try to use the Windows Azure Active Directory User (admin), i get the error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." where I attempt to acquiretoken.

When I use Google, I get an error "0x8010000C: No identity provider matches the requested protocol".

If there is a working sample? if I am doing something obviously wrong, I would appreciate the correction.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported for passive identity providers. IdPs like Google, Facebook, etc. don't want other people collecting credentials for them, as this leads to security issues and possible phishing attacks. They also don't support it because they need to be able to show a permission dialog (that screen that asks the user if they want to release data to you) which they can't do without the browser redirecting to them. Furthermore, Google in particular supports two-factor auth, which you couldn't replicate, and generally collecting credentials opens up whole cans of worms around other UI problems such as incorrect or forgotten passwords.

This is also generally a bad user experience, because your users are fairly likely to already be logged in to Google and have cookies there. If so, and if they've already consented to your app, they would just be silently redirected back to you. In your scenario, even if the user is already logged in they'd still have to provide a username/password.

The correct way to do these sorts of logins is to render a browser control in your app that allows the user to log in at their IdP, which is what AAL helps with.

Comment: Thanks Oren, that makes sense. Does this apply also to Office365 and Windows Azure Active directory? I understand these can be synchronised with on-premises directories, and when accessing a line of business app, the user is familiar with hitting an internal login screen. Is the browser control appropriate in this scenario as well i.e. ask the user to authenticate with WAAD or Office 365 via a browser control?

Sorry if this sounds silly, this is all very new to me.

Comment: It's completely appropriate to have a user log in to O365 or Azure AD using a browser control.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are browser controls the only alternative, are there other way to manage the authentication process? Are there any samples or guides that do this particularly well? That would sort out my learning curve. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, executing a powerscript solved that error

> PS C:\windows\system32> $replyUrl = New-MsolServicePrincipalAddresses
>   -Address https://mydomain.accesscontrol.windows.net/
>
> PS C:\windows\system32> New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames
>   @("https://mydomain.accesscontrol.windows.net/") -DisplayName
>   "MyDomain Namespace" -Addresses $replyUrl

But i'm stuck anyway with a 403 permission error

If you get any further i would like to know how :)